# how to solve the differential equation $\frac{kx^t}{v^2} + 1=\frac{dv}{dx}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

I came across the differential equation in physics

how to solve

$\frac{kx^{1-\gamma}}{v^2} + 1=\frac{dv}{dx}$

given that

$v'(l)=0,v(l)=c,v(0)=0,\gamma>1$

I tried $\frac{1}{v}=\lambda$ but it was of no avail.

I then tried to set up a taylor series with $c_0=0$ but don't know how to proceed

Is there anyway it can be solved using the stuff taught in high school

please help

Comment: How can you define $v$ if you start with $v=0$? The derivative is then undefined.

Comment: take for example ln(x) at x=0 derivative is undefined  but function exists.

Comment: This is of the form of Chini's Equation, not solvable analytically. Is this a computational exercise?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41177/a-nonlinear-first-order-ordinary-differential-equation-ytnat-fracdyt

Comment: @Monocerotis Yes but we can't define $f(x)=\ln{(x)}$ using the ODE $f'(x)=1/x$ and $f(0)=0$. You're implying that the function is defined but is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @Dhanvi Sreenivasan No it wasn't a computational exercise.I used a method not generally used for solving that type of problem and arrived at this ODE.

Comment: how about $f(x)={\frac{sin(x)}{x} - 1}$ $f(0)$ is 0 $f'(0)$ is undefined.